# The April Fools HNQ broken image icons are broken (on high-DPI screens)

Tags: bug, design, hot-questions, april-fools, time-travel-mode

I just encountered the new April Fools theme, and as someone who made my first web page in the 90's, I must say I love it!  The Hot Network Questions sidebar with the animated flames is a particularly nice touch!

But, uh... what happened to the site icons?

[image: Screenshot (broken)]

OK, let me just right-click and select *Inspect*... hmm, OK, seems like they're broken on purpose.  Apparently, they've all been replaced with this icon:

[image: Broken image icon]

OK, that makes sense.  Looks like it's supposed to look like (a kind of a crappy low-res version of) the [classic Netscape broken image icon](https://gizmodo.com/who-designed-clippy-the-history-behind-four-legends-of-659275686). Only, that's still not what it *actually* looks like on the page. :( What's wrong?

Well, apparently, what's wrong is that whoever wrote the CSS for the April Fools theme forgot to <s>set the `background-size` property</s> *test it on high-DPI screens*, so it's still assuming that the new background image has the same dimensions as the [normal icon sprite](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png) (i.e. currently 32px by 13500px, scaled down to 16px by 6750px for higher DPI).  Which means that the browser tries to scale the (20px by 21px) broken image icon up to a height of 6750px, and then only shows the top 16px of the result.

(The normal CSS sprite scaling is only set conditionally based on a CSS `@media` query, so it only affects users with high-DPI screens.  Conveniently, I happen to have an external monitor with a lower DPI than my laptop's built-in display, so I can make this bug appear and disappear just by moving the browser window from one screen to the other.)

Anyway, adding `background-size: 16px 16px` to the CSS makes it look a lot better (and also look the same on both screens):

[image: Screenshot (better)]

Can we please have a quick fix before the day is over? :)

Comment: The "Blog" and "Featured on meta" panels on the right bar have the same problem.

Comment: The broken icons are [by design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382101/1364007): "*All of the icons are actually set to "broken image" icons*".

Answer (score 4):

Since the SE developers have not yet reacted to this extremely urgent bug report, I have added an interim client-side fix for this bug into my [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script.  The fix detects whether Time Travel Mode is active, and applies a `background-size: auto` style to the favicons if it is:

```js
$('.container:has(.tm-unicorn-back) .favicon').filter( function () {
    return /april-fools-2019\/broken-image\.png/.test($(this).css('background-image'));
} ).css('background-size', 'auto');
```

The fix is currently only in the unstable development branch of SOUP, pending further testing that I expect I'll finish in a day or so.  Of course, I hope that Stack Exchange will have noticed and fixed this critical issue by then.  This is important!!!1!11!! :D